# increase image resolution in TCPDF

Tags: image, doctrine, symfony-1.4, tcpdf

I'm using Symfony1.4 with doctrine. I'm generating pdf files using sFTCPDFPlugin. I have a image with resolution 100px × 60px looks fine in browser but when i'm generating a pdf i want to convert this to a high resolution image since the quality is not fine. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

just add a $is_pdf to the action and then use a if/else to decide what image to use higher/lower resolution.

Comment: i want to convert to high resolution on the fly. instead of creating new image.

Comment: But aren't you saying that the image has a 100px x 50px resolution?